# How to get column width inside AS3 DataGrid CellRenderer?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, datagrid, air

I have a DataGrid with one column showing picture icon(s). This is done by using a special CellRenderer. Is it possible to find column width inside the CellRenderer? `this.width` always returns a number that is obviously wrong (152), no matter what the actual column width is. I tried this on PC and on Android.

I need to know the column width to center the picture. It would be probably possible to pass the actual column width to the CellRenderer using a static variable, but I wonder if I'm overlooking something obvious.

```
import fl.controls.listClasses.CellRenderer;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.text.TextFormatAlign;
import flash.utils.*;   
import flash.events.*;

public class CustomImageCellRenderer extends CellRenderer 
{

    public function CustomImageCellRenderer()
    {   

        var iconClass : Class = getDefinitionByName("icon") as Class;
        var iconMC : MovieClip = new iconClass();

        trace("width=" + width); // always returns 152

        addChild(iconMC );      

    }

    override protected function drawBackground():void
    {
        var skin : Object;

        if (_listData.index % 2 == 0)
        {
            skin = CellRenderer_upSkin2;
        } else {
            skin = CellRenderer_upSkin;         
        }           

        setStyle("upSkin", skin);   
        setStyle("overSkin", skin); 
        setStyle("downSkin", skin); 

        setStyle("selectedOverSkin", skin); 
        setStyle("selectedDownSkin", skin);  
        setStyle("selectedUpSkin", skin);

        super.drawBackground();

    }   

}
```

Comment: Maybe you should do it after addChild()  ADDED? Or in ADDED_TO_STAGE event handler?

Comment: That sounds interesting. How would I do it inside the CellRenderer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this.width` in overridden `drawBackground` method:

```
override protected function drawBackground():void
{
    super.drawBackground();
    trace("width=" + this.width);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code! 1) I tried `on_AddedToStage()`. It shows the same width (152), which as turns out is width of the skin MC.


2) `createChildren()` produces an error: “020: Method marked override must override another method.”. I guess that means that I'm not including something, but it's strange since the CellRenderer works.

Comment: Done. BTW, I'm compiling in Animate CC.

Comment: Oh wait a second, you are working in pure Actionscript ? Somehow i thought it's a Flex datagrid since it was tagged with Flex. Then the first part of Nemi's solution (with the added to stage event listener) might help ?

Comment: @user1566515 Great. How did you do it? If my answer helped, please mark your question as answered.

Comment: By "Done" I meant that I edited the question to include the imports. The question is still unsolved :).

Comment: Oh ok :) Could it be that you are missing super() in class constructor?

Comment: Added `super();`, but that made no difference. I don't think that would matter since I'm getting a compile-time error. I guess the only solution would be to move to Flash Builder?

Comment: IMHO Flash Builder is better. But, don't give up here. Did you try parent.width or owner.width  ? Trace `this.width` in `drawBackground()` cause in overridden method `this` is super class, maybe you'll get correct value.

Comment: Flash Builder is better, no question about that, but I still haven't had a chance to switch to it :) `this.width` works inside drawBackground()! Please update your answer so that I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you should do all layout stuff in the updateDisplayList - this is where you should get the correct dimensions:

```
override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledwidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
{
    super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

    icon.x = int((unscaledWidth - icon.width)/2);
}
```

Comment: This sounds great, but I'm getting `1020: Method marked override must override another method.`

Comment: Sorry, since the question was tagged with "Flex" i assumed you're working with a Flex Datagrid

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. I thought that as long as I include Flex libraries it doesn't matter which IDE is used to compile the app. Are you saying that I would need to migrate to Flash Builder in order to override updateDisplayList()?

Comment: Yes, updateDisplayList is a part of the FLex lifecycle and is used to position various things in a component. But have you tried Nemi's solution with the addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, on_AddedToStage);?

Comment: I tried on_AddedToStage(), but It shows the same width. I ended up using an ugly static function that just passes real column width to the CellRenderer. This Flex stuff is confusing:)